# How to retrieve a specific discussion from linkedin group using PHP

Tags: php, linkedin-api

How can I retrieve a specific post/discussion from a open group through LinkedIn API using PHP.

I was trying with the following API request as shown in here http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api#post :

`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/5835685921059532803:(id,type,category,creator,title,summary,creation-timestamp,relation-to-viewer:(is-following,is-liked,available-actions),likes,comments,attachment,site-group-post-url)`

But this returns the following error:

```
Array
(
    [status_code] => 400
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [errorCode] => 0
            [message] => Invalid Post.id String {5835685921059532803}
            [requestId] => XW2XMPBNKY
            [status] => 400
            [timestamp] => 1391441328953
        )

)
```

Now, what's the error I have made with this request? What should I do to get a specific discussion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved the problem. The problem was while making the request. The discussion id `(5835685921059532803)` I was sending with URL was in wrong format. It should be like: `g-GROUP_ID-S-DISCUSSION/POST_ID`, for example: `g-24405-S-5835685921059532803`.

So the URL should be:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/g-24405-S-5835685921059532803:(id,type,category,creator,title,summary,creation-timestamp,relation-to-viewer:(is-following,is-liked,available-actions),likes,comments,attachment,site-group-post-url)`

Hope this would save someone's valuable time.

Answer (score -1):

You need An Api key and Secret key,to get an **AUTHORIZATION_CODE**,using that **AUTHORIZATION_CODE**,you will get an **Access Token**,and with that Access Token if you hit the url,then you will get the proper data,
details http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

Comment: I am not facing problem with authentication. Hope you noticed that, it's a `400` error.

Comment: Yes,the status code 400 means,you have just made an unauthorized request

Comment: When I hit that page it is saying that <message>Unknown authentication scheme</message>,thats why i am saying this

Comment: Please read this first: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/handling-errors-invalid-tokens. `400` means `Bad Request`.